# naming a sessionStorage variable with javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, arguments, session-variables

I'm just trying to name `sessionStorage` variables with an argument in a JavaScript function, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Is it possible? Code below...

```
function checkJob(a){
    sessionStorage.job+a = 0; 
}
```

the variables being sessionStorage.jobBuilder, sessionStorage.jobPostman etc

I've tried using single quotes but that doesn't work either. Hope it's possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to concatenate or add `job` to `a` use the other refinement operator `[]`.

```
function checkJob(a){
    sessionStorage['job' + a] = 0; 
}
```

Comment: but sessionStorage['job' + a] = 0; seems to have done, many thanks